# @nestjs-modules/mailer has deprecated packages (vm2 npm)

Tags: nestjs

When a trying to install @nestjs-modules/mailer, I received this message:

> *The library contains critical security issues and should not be used for production! The maintenance of the project has been discontinued. Consider migrating your code to isolated-vm.*

Obviously, i don't feel safe working with this package. Do you know how to solve this issue? How to send an email with nestJs in a secure way?

I'm trying to send emails in a secure way with NestJS, and I need documentation without deprecated packages.

Answer (score 0):

I'm cutting out the third party wrapper module and using [`nodemailer`](https://nodemailer.com/) directly [in my side project](https://github.com/jmcdo29/unteris/tree/main/libs/server/email). Pretty easy to write your own wrapper module and modify as necessary.

[There is a merged PR](https://github.com/nest-modules/mailer/pull/1021), but it is unreleased and it seems many people in the comments have moved away from the package as well

Answer (score 0):

hope my answer helps,

Its because one of the `@nestjs-modules/mailer` nested dependencies - `degenerator` uses as dependency `vm2` package, but now `vm2` is vulnerable.
Thats why in the latest major update of `degenator` they switched from `vm2` to `quickjs-emscripten`, here is the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/TooTallNate/proxy-agents/blob/main/packages/degenerator/CHANGELOG.md).

In our project we updated `degenerator` to latest version to avoid vulnerability issues.

```
"resolutions": {
    "degenerator": "5.0.1"
 }
```

Or you can use other package for mailing.

Dependency graph of [`@nestjs-modules/mailer`](https://npmgraph.js.org/?q=%40nestjs-modules%2Fmailer) package